# Intent does not start during application run

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am facing an issue when trying to run my application on my emulator.

Sometimes, the process seems to go well (until the console says `"Starting activity [..]"`), but it stops here so the line that usually says `"ActivityManager: Starting: Intent ([...]`)" never shows up, and my application does not start on my emulator.

Then when i change some code in my main activity, it works, but the lines I am changing have nothing to do with `intent` or `activity`.

Any clue on what is going on?

Here is the manifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sdcompyan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Also, it happens frequently that the the emulator "timesout" when trying to launchthe application.

Comment: Could you post your manifest file or some code within your application please?

Comment: The Timeout can be fixed by Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android Tab -> DDMS -> set ADB connection timeout to 20000 or another large number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well it sounds like there is no problem with your main activity code or manifest file. Chances are you code is absolutely perfect and instead it is a problem with your emulator.

The problem with using an emulator over an actual device is that is doesn't always run as smooth or as efficient as an actual device. Because of this your app may not act the same every time you run it on an emulator, such as the emulator failing to start your application successfully on installation.

My best solution would be to get an actual device and I would bet you won't ever notice this problem again, but that isn't ways possible so you may just have to stick it out with using the emulator.

If your app won't start up successfully on installation you can always view the apps page on the emulator which will have your app listed within it, along with all of the apps on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clean your emulator when run your app.
Right click on the project you want to run --> Run Configuration --> Target --> Check Wipe User data